What wallets support ethereum etf? Coinbase delisted etf eth and now I'm looking for a new wallet
What walletes support ethereum etf?
Counbase wallet delisted etf eth

Crypto wallets do not support ETH ETF. ETFs are part of traditional finance. Instead to invest in Ethereum (ETH) you can use Metamask (https://metamask.io/) to hold ETH.

Well then why did coinbase wallet let me buy it?

Can you send the contract address of what you bought, or a screenshot?
